# Read Hamikra VeHamassora (Reuvein Margulies) online

Tags: jewish-books, internet, books-generally

Is there anywhere the book Hamikra veHamassora (המקרא והמסורה) of R' Reuvein Margulies, online ?

A lot of his books are on https://hebrewbooks.org/, but not this one, and I would like to see at least the first pages with the summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 40 pages are viewable on [Otzar HaChochmah](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=155132) for free, which is 4/7 of the book.